# Where is task manager / task switcher configuration stored in a system with LXQT + Openbox?

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, openbox, lxqt, task-management

I am using LUbuntu 20.04, which comes with LXQT + Openbox. I am searching for the config files to see why my task switcher is showing all applications in all desktops instead of only applications from current desktop. It's weird, because the task bar is working as intended (showing only apps from current desktop) but task switcher is not.

I am a newbie in this subject. I don't know whether the task switcher is the same app as the task manager, I don't know if both are responsibility of the Desktop Environment (LXQT) or the Window Manager (Openbox) and I don't know where to find the exact config files to check what is happening :). So I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I'll try to clarify my question. When you right click in the bottom panel (LXQT + Openbox) and choose `Configure "Task Manager"` it shows a menu where I can select `Show only windows from Desktop: Current`. This way the bottom panel shows only application windows from the current desktop, and that's good. But when I press Ctrl + Tab, the task switcher (or window switcher, I don't know how to call it) is showing application windows from ALL desktops, not only from the current desktop.

So I was wondering whether the `Task Manager` who shows windows in the bottom panel is the same application as the `Task/Window Switcher`, because they seem to act desynchronized (at least in my computer). And that way see where is the desynchronization.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking sorry (*likely also I'm tired*) but I'll provide https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/ which I find a handy resource; you'll note the task manager is `qps`.  Most of desktop is handled by `pcmanfm-qt` with the panel/taskbar bing `pxqt-panel`  but LXQt is WM agnostic so Lubuntu uses `openbox` to provide the window management (borders etc).  Are you aware of our manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/  (change *lts* to *stable* to read the latest stable version; currently 21.10)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I added more information to the question in order to clarify it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem. In the keys binding configuration file (now in ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml) the combination config for switching between windows is `A-Tab`. That's right, but there's also an option called `<allDesktops>`. In my case it said `yes`, I changed it to `no` and now it shows only windows from the current desktop.